# How to set nautilus to --no-desktop via gconf

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, gconf, openbox

I need to set --no-desktop via gconf for nautilus, I use OpenBox.  I used to just set it like this

```
# Disable Nautilus desktop.
gconftool-2 -s -t bool /apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop false &
# Do not let Nautilus set the background image.
gconftool-2 -s -t bool /desktop/gnome/background/draw_background false &
```

However, I find this does not work in Ubuntu 11.10.  Has something changed in gconf?  Might it have anything to do with Gsettings?  In the mean time, I just added --no-desktop to my .desktop shortcuts.  This is not a solid long term solution for me, for a few reasons.  Anytime you upgrade the nautilus package, those changes will overwrite.  Much more importantly,  Anything that launches nautilus another way wont use --no-desktop.  If anyone  can help, it would be much appreciated.

BTW: gconf-editor let me view my settings, but no schema for nautilus even existed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, in Gnome 3, Gconf is being replaced by DConf, which is accessed through GSettings. You can use dconf-editor from the [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools) package to explore. It's very similar to gconf-editor.

The entries your looking for are located at *org -> gnome -> desktop -> background*

Uncheck *draw-background* AND *show-desktop-icons*

[image]

No more openbox menu and wallpaper problems :)

Comment: can you update your answer ? I tried the solution but it's still showing up the nautilius background even when I uncheck the draw-background

Comment: am using 12.10 Ubuntu + openbox

Comment: The question was about 11.10. Things may have changed since then, and I don't use 12.10. Perhaps a new answer should be added?

Comment: on 14.04, works fine

Comment: on 16.04.1, works fine.

Comment: This does not work for me on 16.04.  What did work was `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false`.

Answer (score 3):

The setting mentioned in Jo-Erlend Schinstad's answer has been deprecated and I can't find a new equivalent setting. A workaround is to let the file manager set the background but set the alpha to zero. The command for this is

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-opacity 0
```

or you can use the `dconf-editor` gui to set it as discussed in Jo-Erlend Schinstad's answer.

The setting to hide the desktop icons is still the same:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/background/show-desktop-icons false
```

Comment: For me it was sufficient to set the show-desktop-icons to false.

Comment: Just tested and yep, that seems to work. I'll try it out on some more computers before I edit the answer because it seems weird...