# Problem with Nautilus when using awesome?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, awesome

When I start `awesome` with `startx` I have no background (by choice) and when I right click on the "desktop" I get a menu for opening apps like in normal GNOME.

The problem is that when I start Nautilus it basically starts Unity's desktop with the default Ubuntu background and the right-click menu from the Unity desktop how can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, start Nautilus with:

```
nautilus --no-desktop
```

Comment: Yes, but "*Much more importantly, Anything that launches nautilus another way wont use --no-desktop.*" from [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/87829/25656). So a more general solution would be nice.

Comment: the answer in the other question doesnt work for 12.04+ guess ill have to use this answer for now