# When I run Nautilus or Guake from awesome wm the wallpaper is reverted to my Unity background

Tags: unity, gnome, nautilus, awesome, guake

I'm using awesome wm on a ubuntu 12.04. It works fine except that *whenever*  I run guake or nautilus should the background being reverted back to what's my background on unity.

on using nautilus,  there's a simple workaround that I've found here

[Problem with Nautilus when using awesome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260008/problem-with-nautilus-when-using-awesome)

But is there a permanent configuration to set here so as to not conflict with awesome?

But I haven't found a solution yet when using guake.

Answer (score 3):

1. Install dconf-tools

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
   ```
2. Open `dconf-editor`.
3. Search for org > gnome > desktop > background
4. Uncheck "draw-background" and "show-desktop-icons".

Good Luck!

P.S. I have no experience with awesome wm and cannot test my solution, but I really think this should solve your problem. I am sorry in advance to steal your time if it does not work.

Edit:
I overread the Guake Part of the question. I am not sure if you want the Unity background or not, but there is "Guake Preferences" installed with Guake, where you can set a background or switch transparency off to get what you want. or not?

Comment: thanks for your answer.
but i've tried all the steps but still the problem occurs.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.10, I had to use `dconf-editor` instead of `dconf-tools`.

Answer (score 2):

You could modify the /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop so it says in the line

```
Exec= nautilus --no-desktop
```

It should be the third line

Comment: sorry didin't seem to work

Comment: thanks for your answer.
i've tried it. But it doesn't work

Comment: you could also try the prized solution, sorry for commenting that late

Answer (score 0):

I realise this post is rather old but I just thought of a possible permanent configuration. Although this looks like and probably is a workaround it should fix your issue permanently, that is, if you are launching nautilus with the nautilus command.

```
alias nautilus='nautilus --no-desktop'
```

I do not know about guake.