# Openbox configuration issue

Tags: nautilus, desktop-environments, openbox

So I installed openbox in 16.04 and was setting about configuring it.  All was going as expected - gray background, no panel yet etc.  Then I opened Nautilus and got a prompt that I confirmed without reading, something about defaults, and when nautilus opened up my background changed to the Ubuntu default.

What happened, and how can I undo it?

Answer (score 4):

Once you open nautilus, a daemon stays open and this controls the background.  So once you've started the nautilus daemon, just find the nautilus process and kill it, and then you can control your background again.

There are some permanent fixes here, but none worked for me: [How to set nautilus to --no-desktop via gconf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87829/how-to-set-nautilus-to-no-desktop-via-gconf).  A solution would be to open nautilus with --no-desktop, but you'd have to figure out which .desktop file is pointed at by your panel.

The real fix was this: run `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false` (found here: https://askubuntu.com/a/237984/155311).

Comment: Great answer. Good research. I personally would use thunar/xfce tools because they are light-weight, and don't assimilate your desktop.